# throw error and use finally block sends error code 500

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, error-handling, try-catch

I'm using a  `throwExecption` when a file is not specified in request and at the end of my fonction I use `finally` block to unlink file.

So I case `file` is not specified I should get 400 code with error message.

But because of `finally` block `throw Execption` is getting overrided by it

```
try {
  if (!file) {
    throw new BadRequestException('no file');
  } 
}
...
finally {
  // On error or not : delete temporary file
    await fse.unlink(file.path); // error 500 because Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
}
```

I have found a workaround  if to check file in `finally` block , but that makes code redundant.

```
try {
  if (!file) {
    throw new BadRequestException('no file');
  } 
}
...
finally {
  // On error or not : delete temporary file
  if (file) {
    await fse.unlink(file.path);
  } else {
    throw new BadRequestException('no file'); <== redundancy
  }
}
```

Is there another way to handle this case of error ?

Comment: why put it in a try catch if you want to throw the exception - surely if you don't have a file then the exception should be thrown and the program exits at that point?  That way anyone calling the service will know that an error has occurred (rather than it silently being swallowed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the *if block* outside of try/catch block

```js
if (!file) {
  try {
    ...your block of code
  }
  ...
  finally {
    // On error or not : delete temporary file
    await fse.unlink(file.path);
  }

} else {
  throw new BadRequestException('no file'); <= = redundancy
}
```